# .exe file closes when i click the button in the userinterface which is supposed to play music file

Tags: c++, qt, audio-player

Im new in QT , i want to play a music file through QT ,with the interface containing a single play button ,so that when i click the play button the song should play.now when i run the program,i get my interface but unfortunately when i click the play button,it says the .exe file stopped working ,and it gets closed down ,with an exit error code of 255 getiing dispalyed in QT creator window..here is the main window.cpp file

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "audiere.h"
using namespace audiere;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    //connect(ui->Number1,SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)),this,SLOT(numberChanged()));
    connect(ui->play,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(PLAY()));

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::PLAY() {
    AudioDevicePtr device(OpenDevice());
    OutputStreamPtr sound(OpenSound(device,"lk.mp3",true));

    sound->play();
    sound->setRepeat(true);
    sound->setVolume(2.0);

}
```

Comment: What platform are you running it on? Do you get any information if you run it from a debugger?

Comment: Same question as [this].(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15239513/segmentation-fault-when-using-qt-and-the-audiere-library)  I'm going to guess that `OpenDevice` failed to return a valid pointer.

Comment: im runnning it on windows 7 ,i get ar eroor code of 255 when it i run this

Answer (score 0):

I have three recommendations:

First, add in error checking.

Second, consider using Ogg Vorbis, if you are having problems with mp3's.

Third, move your pointers to be member variables of MainWindow instead of local scope variables.  Audiere is probably cleaning them up prematurely.

### Using Error Checking in Audiere

This is from "tutorial.txt" that ships in the doc folder of the Audiere download:

You need to open an AudioDevice before you can play sounds...

```
AudioDevicePtr device(OpenDevice());
if (!device) {
    // failure
}
```

Now that we have a device, we can actually open and play sounds.

```
/*
 * If OpenSound is called with the last parameter = false, then
 * Audiere tries to load the sound into memory.  If it can't do
 * that, it will just stream it.
 */
OutputStreamPtr sound(OpenSound(device, "effect.wav", false));
if (!sound) {
  // failure
}

/*
 * Since this file is background music, we don't need to load the
 * whole thing into memory.
 */
OutputStreamPtr stream(OpenSound(device, "music.ogg", true));
if (!stream) {
  // failure
}
```

Great, we have some opened streams!  What do we do with them?

### FAQ Info about recent MP3 support

There also is a caveat in the faq page:

> As of the 1.9.2 release, Audiere supports MP3 thanks to the splay
>   library.  However, there is very little LGPL-compatible MP3 code out
>   there that works across a wide range of MP3s and hardware.  I highly
>   recommend using Ogg Vorbis for all of your music needs.  It uses
>   less CPU time by about a factor of five *and* sounds better.

### When Audiere does Clean Up

And at the bottom of the tutorial it mentions when clean up happens:

> When you are done using Audiere, just let the RefPtr objects go out of
>   scope, and they will automatically clean themselves up.  If you really
>   *must* delete an object before its pointer goes out of scope, just set the pointer to 0.

Hope that helps.

Comment: there is the failure of sound, i.e 
if (!sound) {
  // failure
}
this statement gets executed...could you please tell how to handle this now..
I tried using stream as well, nothing happens , also used ogg file ,but the problem persisits